# Eclipse cdt use a library in two projects

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm new to c, and used Eclipse for Java development. I think this is already covered but i'm not sure what to search.

I have two projects:

- Client
- Server

I want to create a third project `MyLibrary` to write some code that will be used both from the `Client` and `Server` projects.
How to do this in Eclipse? In java i would usually add the project as a dependency, but i'm not sure how it works with c.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have created your MyLibrary project as library, just do the following:

1. Open your projects property sheet (right-click project, select **Properties**)
2. Select C/C++ Build --> Settings
3. The **Tool Settings** tab should be opened now.
4. Select GCC Linker --> Libraries
5. Add the name of the library (e.g mylibrary - no extension or prefixes) to the upper window.
6. Add the path to the library to the lower window

Do this to both of your projects (Client and Server) and you're done.

Comment: Thanks! But how can i reference the library in the code? I have MyLibrary/utils/util.h how can i import it inside Server/main.c?

Comment: Just add the include to your source file: **#include "utils/util.h"** and after you have done this, go to your projects properties again, but this time, don't select the **Linker** but **GCC Compiler --> Includes**. Now add the path to your libraries source path to the **Include Paths** (so the folder, where the directory **utils** is placed).